# Each individual or group is/are

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

When using *each* combined with *or* , which is correct:

> Each individual or group is happy.
>
> Each individual or group are happy.
>
> Each individual or group is filled with laughter.
>
> Each individual or group are filled with laughter.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Because it may be a duplicate? Because it may be *perceived* as (a) homework (dump)? In both cases, the correct action is to close it(?).

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Is or Are with OR?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16349)* (in its example sentence: *"If e1 or e2* ***are*** positioned..."* vs. *"If e1 or e2* ***is*** *positioned..."* )

Answer (score 0):

I would use "is" here, and I think "are" is incorrect. A group may be composed of many things or people, but it is a single thing for purposes of this sentence.

In general, I would use

> Each A or B is .

and never "are" in this construction. Even when B is in itself a plural noun.